I have a question about the selective chlorination mechanism of galactopyranosyl-(1 -> 6)-O-a-D-glucopyranosyl-(1 -> 2)-D-fructofuranoside
Could you please provide a full mechanism of selective chlorination of galactopyranosyl-(1 -> 6)-O-a-D-glucopyranosyl-(1 -> 2)-D-fructofuranoside using the TPP/thionyl chloride as a chlorinating agent in the presence of pyridine? The selective chlorination in this case occurs on position 4 of glucose moiety with inversion of stereochemistry, positions 1' and 6' of fructose moiety and position 6'' of galactose moiety.

Your TPP is triphenyl phosphine or something else?

yes, TPP is triphenylphosphine
